# UITableView Cell background like in 'Music' app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting background color of a table view cell on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900094/setting-background-color-of-a-table-view-cell-on-iphone)
>   [how to change the color alternate cell on table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945615/how-to-change-the-color-alternate-cell-on-table-view)

I want to have one cell with normal background and the next one with somewhat great background like in this screenshot:
[image]
Any ideas in how to implement this nice and clean for an unlimited number of cells?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is a "great" background...What have you tried?  How about these:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213364/how-to-change-the-backgroundcolor-for-all-uitableviewcells http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900094/setting-background-color-of-a-table-view-cell-on-iphone?lq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281515/how-to-customize-the-background-color-of-a-uitableviewcell The second one is pretty much exactly your question.  In fact, this is basically a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FizzBuzz:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if ((indexPath.row % 2) == 0) {
        [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
    else {
        [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:243.0f/255.0f green:243.0f/255.0f blue:243.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
        [cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:243.0f/255.0f green:243.0f/255.0f blue:243.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [songArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This approach is fine unless you have any editing accessory in the cell. This code I tried `[cell.accessoryView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:243.0f/255.0f green:243.0f/255.0f blue:243.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];` isn't working